# How to match only whitespace and letter with regex in flutter?

Tags: flutter

have this input

```
2019-12-04T21:24:24 or 2019-12-04 21:24:24
```

I tried to match if "T" is present or " " is present

I see two solutions

match all between 10 and 11 lenght
 match only letter and whitespace

I tried this but nothing happen

```
^[a-zA-Z]{10,11}$
^.{10,11}$
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to solve the datetime issue. What is your actual issue with date time?

Comment: I save two date one in Iso8601 and one standard. Iso8601 caracteristic is T and standard is whitespace, so I need to match this difference to make the good calcul

Comment: convert  Iso8601 to standard can be a solution

Comment: Above one, you can just check if the input contains "T" right. There's no way there will be another "T" char exist! If it contain "T" do your thing else you know that it has space

Comment: Yes only T or space, but if match only for (T), when I have space my code interrupt in the regex because math is null . So i search an expression who match T or space to not interrupt the code

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misunderstanding in your regex : what you've written means "Does the input is equivalent to a succession of 10 or 11 characters?", which will always be false for a DateTime. You should select the 11th letter then check if this character matches `(T|\s)` (either the letter T or a space).

Comment: possibly ^^ I have a lot of trouble understanding regex mechnism. I found somes example on web who is close to my problem, but without understand, I spent too much time searching so I ask for help :)

Comment: I tried ^(T|\s)$ but nothing  with this input 2019-12-04T24:12:02

Comment: if I write like this (T|\s+) it's ok

Comment: I agree :) To make things short :
- `^` defines the beginning of the string to check and `$` defines the end
- `\s` is a space character, `\d` any numerical character and `\w` any "literal" character
- To check if the word is a letter or a number, check if it respects the pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (either a lowercase or uppercase letter, or a number)
- You can check if it is a succession of the same pattern by writing `{m,n}` just after (means that your word contains between `m` and `n` characters respecting this pattern), or only `{n}` if `m == n`.
Hope it'll sum up your searches :)

Comment: `\s+` means that you are looking for an undefined number of successive spaces, at least one space.
You're right for `^$`, I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You want

```js
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[T ][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5aFIYq/1/).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` - four digits, `-`, two digits, `-`, two digits
- `[T ]` - `T` or a space
- `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` - two digits, `:`, two digits, `:`, two digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score -1):

just add this code to your `textfield`

for example:

```
inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[ آ-ی]"))],
```

for space just space in your list `RegExp`